# Then prove that $g \rightarrow L_g$ is a group homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For any group $G$ any $g \in G$, let $L_g:G \rightarrow G$ be the function $L_g(h)=gh$ and $R_g:G \rightarrow G$ be the function $R_g(h)=hg$. Let $S_G$ be the group of permutations of the group $G$ considered only as a set.

Then prove that $g \rightarrow L_g$ is a group homomorphism. What is the kernel of this homomorphism?

**Doubt:**

Can someone clarify what the question is trying to ask. The notation seems wrong to me. Now clarified

**My attempt:**

$L_g(h_1h_2)=g(h_1h_2)$ and $L_g(h_1) \cdot L_g(h_2)=(gh_1) \cdot (gh_2)$

How do I show $L_g(h_1h_2)=L_g(h_1) \cdot L_g(h_2)$

What is the kernel of this group homomorphism?

I think it is $G$ because $e$ is the identity of $G$ and $e$ gets mapped to $L_e=G$

Comment: What exactly is unclear? You're trying to show that the map $G \to S_G$ given by $g \to L_g$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: @anomaly Now this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Normally you would use different arrow for a definiton of a mapping: $g\mapsto L_g$ unlike $G\to S_G$ which only defines a domain and codomain.

Comment: @freakish Can you please give me a hint

Comment: You are not trying to show that $L_g$ is a group homomorphism for each $g$, you are trying to show that $g\mapsto L_g$ is a group homomorphism as a function of $g$.

Answer (score 2):

For each $g\in G$ we have a left-multiplication function $L_g$ defined by $L_g(x)=gx$.

It is not true that $L_g$ itself will be a group homomorphism. In fact, since $L_g(e)=g$ and group homomorphisms preserve identities, it will *only* be a group homomorphism if $g=e$.

Consider the function $\mathrm{Left}:G\to \mathrm{Perm}(G)$ (where $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ is the group of permutations of $G$'s underlying set) defined by $\mathrm{Left}(g)=L_g$. You want to show that $\mathrm{Left}$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: @user330477 On which part? What don't you understand?

Comment: The function and perm(G) part

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write what $\mathrm{Left}$ is. It is the function which takes $g$ as input and outputs $L_g$. As for the $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ part, surely you know what a permutation is?

Comment: I think with the edit you've touched on what will clear things up for the OP; their work is trying to show that $L_g : G \to G$ is a homomorphism, but they believe it to be the work required to show that the map $g \mapsto L_g$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: @arctictern What is the kernel of homomorphism. I think it is G

Comment: @user330477 So you're saying $L_g$ is the identity function for all $g\in G$?

Comment: @arctictern I don't know how to describe it and I am getting confused.

Comment: The homomorphism we're talking about is from $G$ to $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$. The group operation in $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ is function composition. The kernel will be the set of all $g\in G$ that get mapped to the identity element of $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$, in other words the identity function. What does it mean for $L_g$ to be the identity function? It means $L_g(x)=x$ for all $x$. In other words, $gx=x$ for all $x$. For what values of $g$ is that true?

Comment: @arctictern So is the kernel just the set of the identity of $G$?

Comment: Yes, the kernel is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you need to prove that

$$L_{g_{\large 1}g_{\large 2}} = L_{g_{\large 1}}\circ L_{g_{\large 2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I think this clears everything up.

Comment: What is the kernel of homomorphism. I think it is just $G$

Comment: @user330477, $g$ is is in the kernel iff $L_g =$ identity iff...

Answer (score 0):

$L$ is a group homomorphism iff $L_{gh}=L_gL_h$ for evey $g,h\in G$. But $L_g$ is itself a map, so two maps are equal iff they return the same value when both are evaluated at every same element of the domain. So, $L_{gh}=L_gL_h$ iff, for every $k\in G$, $L_{gh}(k)=(L_gL_h)(k)$ iff, for every $k\in G$, $(gh)k=g(hk)$, which true because the associative property holds in groups. Therefore, $L$ is a group homomorphism.

By definition, its kernel is made of the elements $g\in G$ such that $L_g$ is the identity map of $G$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&L_g=Id_G &&\iff \\
&\forall h\in G: L_g(h)=Id_G(h) &&\iff \\
&\forall h\in G: gh=h &&\iff \\
&g=1_G
\end{alignat}
Therefore, $\ker L=\{1_G\}$. The isomorphic image of $G$ into $S_G$ given by $L_G$ is said the left regular representation of $G$.