# Use $l_g$ to show certain properties of $r_g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $(G, *)$ a group and the two applications $l_g, r_g: G \rightarrow G$ so that $l_g(x) = gx$ and $r_g(x) = xg$. I have already showed that $l_{g_1} \circ l_{g_2} = l_{g_1 g_2}$, $l_g$ is a bijective function but not an homomorphism. Is there a way to prove the same things without doing the hard work? I've seen that $r_g(x) = l_g(g^{-1} x g)$. Does this relation is sufficient to show that $r_{g_1} \circ r_{g_2} = r_{g_1 g_2}$, $r_g$ is a bijective function but not an homomorphism?

**EDIT:**

I have proved that $c_g: G \rightarrow G$ such that $c_g(x) = g^{-1}xg$ is an isomorphism. Can I use that using the fact that $r_g(x) = l_g(g^{-1} x g) = l_g \circ c_g (x)$?

Comment: In semigroup theory, there is often a left and a right version of things, and sometimes one can simple say, "dually", to mean that the same argument that works with one, works for the other.

Comment: Which "hard work"? By the way, the map $g\mapsto L_g$ is a group homomorphism, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221476/then-prove-that-g-rightarrow-l-g-is-a-group-homomorphism?rq=1), but this is not what you are looking at?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not sure this is what I want to prove. To be stupid, I will prove again that $r_g$ is bijective (not an homomorphism necessarily) and $r_{g_1} \circ r_{g_2} = r_{g_1 g_2}$. I just want to prove it using the right way knowing I proved the same property with $l_g$.

Comment: Well, technically if you include the group $G$ in the notation, and define $(G^{op}, *^{op})$ to be that $G^{op}$ has the same underlying set as $G$ but with $x *^{op} y := y * x$, then $r_{G,g}(x) = l_{G^{op},g}(x)$.  Therefore, for example, $r_{G,g_1} \circ r_{G,g_2} = l_{G^{op},g_1} \circ l_{G^{op},g_2} = l_{G^{op}, g_1 *^{op} g_2} = r_{G, g_2 * g_1}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that $r_{g_1}r_{g_2}=r_{g_1g_2}$. Rather:
$$(r_gr_h)(x)=r_g(r_h(x))=r_g(xh)=(xh)g=x(hg)=r_{hg}(x)$$
and hence $r_{hg}=r_gr_h$. So, $g\mapsto l_g$ is a homomorphism (it's true that $l_g$ is a bijection but not a homomorphism), while $g\mapsto r_g$ is an *antihomomorphism*.